# how can i make an ID auto increment and hidden from user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm working on C# MVC 4 web app

i created a page linked to a DB and my question is that in the Create New record the user can enter the ID, Name, ...

how can i hide in the View from the user the ID and make it take an auto incremental number for example when the user goes to page  Create New he will have to start filling the Name, Address ... without seeing the ID field which must take automatically the value of a number:

here is my model code:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Identifier { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the view and remove the ID part from it, then it depends by how you designed the DB, if you have auto-increment in it, otherwise you should manage it in the controller.
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

You should let the DB handle the Id incrementation. I would set the Id to private in case you need it for business operations. But you can remove it from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use a AutoIncrement database field. 
[Here are some common ways to do that](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

If after your INSERT INTO statement you want to get the ID your database generated put

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

for SQL Server to return the ID it generated.

Comment: .... 0r use an ORM like Entity Framework which will automagically return the newly inserted `ID` in your object after it's been saved ....

Answer (score -1):

Usually you use a `Guid` to represent an ID. The reason for this is that you can not know the last ID of the last inserted entity (in your case Employee). To find it you you insert it into the database (let the db handle the increment) and the database server responds with the incremented ID.

To know the exact ID of the inserted entity use a `Guid`. The `Guid` is a very large integer that has a very small chance of being idendical to another inserted Guid. Thus you wont have to wait for the database to respond with the inserted ID.

Note you can not bast the Guid to an int. You have to change the field type.

Comment: Guid is not an integer and as a note for the OP, the default value of the column can be set to NewID()

Comment: @Silvermind This is from MSDN `A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx Also I was suggesting a better approach.

Comment: I never noticed that remark on msdn, but it is rather confusing to say so. I wouldn't say that msdn is wrong here, but it would be more clear if it said that it represents a 128 bit integer.